# Arranging Elements in CSS according to the size of screen

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how would I Arrange the postion of my elements in my CSS like top,left, align, and so on and so forth? take a look at my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Avril Lavigne</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="style/style.css"

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id = "container">

        <div id="banner"><img src = "images/banner.jpg"/></div>

        <div id = "content">

        <div id = "about">
        <h1>About Avril Lavigne</h1>

        <p>
        Avril Ramona Lavigne is a Canadian singer-songwriter. 
        She was born in Belleville, Ontario, but spent most of her youth in the small 
        town of Napanee. By the age of 15, she had appeared on stage with Shania Twain; by 16, 
        she had signed a two-album recording contract with Arista Records worth more than $2 million.
        In 2002, when she was 17 years old, Lavigne broke onto the music scene with her debut album Let Go.
        </p>
        </div>  

                <div id ="tourdates">
                <h2> Tour dates</h2>
                </div>

        </div>  
        </div>

    </body>

<html>
```

my CSS

```
body{
    background-color:#292929;
    font-size:small;
}

#container{
    padding: 420px;
    margin:120px;
    border: 5px dotted pink;
}


#banner{
top: 150px;
left: 450px;
right:450px;
position:absolute;
}

#about{
font-size: 100%;
font-family: tahoma;
color: #8B3A62;
position:absolute;
top:320px;
left: 440px;
padding: 20px;
width:320px;
length: 120px;
margin:10px;
border: dashed 2px white;
}

#tourdates{
color: #8B3A62;
padding: 20px;
top:320px;
right: 540px;
position:absolute;
border: dotted 2px white
}
```

The banner is suposed to be at the middle center, and the about should 1/4 or the top left of it(top left below the banner). How would set the sizes of the top, left,side depending on the users screen?

My Problem  here was when I was at my workspace(my other house) they are well aligned, but when I went to my laptop to continue my work their alignment changed.(my laptop has a smaller screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @media screen and then you simply change css if screen size is different
Here is an example (couple of things in css changed if screen is under 700px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
 {
  /*.figure
    {
        margin-right: 3.317535545023696682%;   
        width: 41.902053712480252764%; 

    }*/
    #mail
    {
        padding-left:0px;
    }
    body
    {
        font-size:0.8em;
    }
    h5
    {
        font-size:0.9em;
    }
        #my_profile_image
    {
        height:160px;
        width:160px;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the answer I gave you up there is little more advanced, I used it when I changed look of my page, depending on if it's opened in browser or on mobile phone, ipad etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

`position: relative;`

to your #container declaration? This will position all absolute-positioned child elements within the #container tag.

2nd run:

```
body{
    background-color:#292929;
    font-size:small;
}

#container{
    border: 5px dotted pink;

    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
    right: 120px;
    bottom: 120px;
    min-height: 615px;
    min-width: 900px;
}


#banner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}

#about{
    position:absolute;
    top: 320px;
    right: 32%;
    left: 30px;

    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: #8B3A62;
    padding: 20px;
    border: dashed 2px white;
}

#tourdates{
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    left: 70%;
    right: 30px;

    color: #8B3A62;
    padding: 20px;
    border: dotted 2px white
}
```

Comment: what does position relative do? should I edit the width of my container tag?

Comment: i edited some css in my reply. this will change the layout depending on the screen size. please notice the min-width and min-height declarations. what should the layout look like?

Comment: The one you gave me is almost correct, the banner needs to be centered and that's it, and may I ask. how did you make it/how did you do it ? that no matter how the big/small the screen size of the user it is still in the same format as it was before? I am getting kinda slow picking this up